# ebay API - Get promoted listings

Tags: ebay-api

Using the Ebay Api I want to query whether any listings have promoted listings associated with them.

Using the Marketing API I've tried: `getCampaigns` and `getPromotions`.
On the Trading API I've tried: `getPromotionalSaleDetails`.

The standard `getSellerList` call doesn't return promoted listing data.

I'm hoping there is an API call that will return all listings that have "promoted listings" on them, or a list of campaigns that will give me an id number that I can use to look up the relevant listings.

**Edit**

According to the documentation for the [getCampaign](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/marketing/resources/campaign/methods/getCampaigns) api call, campaigns created through the eBay website ("eBay web flow") are not returned via this method. Of course, all the campaigns I want to retrieve were created via the eBay website. And the documentation doesn't point the developer to where this data can be retrieved. Probably because it doesn't exist. The eBay [forum](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/36265/promoted-listings-api-getcampaigns-returns-zero-1.html) mentions this.